# Method "XY" targeted by Callback constraint does not exist

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.6.

That's my Entity User.php:

```
(...)
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateFirstName"}, groups={"registration"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string")
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateFirstName"}, groups={"registration"})
     */
    public function validateFirstName(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        // somehow you have an array of "fake names"
        //$fakeNames = array(/* ... */);
        $firstname = $this->getFirstName();
        // check if the name is actually a fake name
        if ( "" == $firstname) {
            $context->buildViolation('This name sounds totally fake!')
                ->atPath('firstName')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
(...)
```

and I got the error:
Method "validateFirstName" targeted by Callback constraint does not exist

I really don't know why, because of

```
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateFirstName"}
```

Can someone explain, how can I connect the method with $firstname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently on 2.3 so I can't check this directly for you, but at a glance it looks like you're not following the documentation with regards to annotations.

Looking at the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html), I don't think you need the @Assert annotation on the $firstname property.

Also looking at the documentation with your validator being a method in your User.php you should just need @Assert\Callback() on your validateFirstName method.

E.g.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string")
 */
private $firstname;

/**
 * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validateFirstName(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
```

Simplify it down as per the documentation and see if that works, then add validation groups after you've proved it.

Comment: Finally with your tip, I found the solution: `/**
  * @var string
  * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string")
  */
 private $firstname;

 /**
  * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
  * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateFirstName"}, groups={"registration"})
  */
 public function validateFirstName(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
 {`
So, only in the Method using `@Assert`, than you have the connection between the both! :-)

Comment: This would be nice, to have it also in the documentation. But for all, where googling it: Just put it only above your method, not Assert at all in the variable.